# Leaflet/GeoJSON - Adding properties into GeoJSON with an input form in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, user-input, geojson

I am currently creating an application with Leaflet. I'm using the leaflet.draw plugin to create polygons, and the bootboxjs plugin (from Bootstrap [bootboxjs.com/examples.html]) to enter the information (= properties) I want (ideally a title and some lines of text). I would like some help to get the data (=text) I write when creating the polygons to fit into the GeoJSON properties (I then save it in that format, but later I would like it to save to a SQL database, but that's another story). Actually, this information is only display in the popup I created...

I managed to provide properties directly from the Javascript when creating the polygons, but ideally I would like to enter the properties directly when creating the polygons.

Here is an extract of the (functional) code of the leaflet draw part, and my console.log result: It's show title and content from JavaScript... I don't know if I have to use some ajax or html part into this too.

[image: view of the console.log from the geojson]

For resume : How can I insert properties into a newly created polygon into Leaflet?

```
var type = e.layerType,
                        layer = e.layer;
                    var layer = e.layer;

                    bootbox.prompt({                       //// enter text here this is the input text I want to add into the properties of my geoJSON.
                        title: "Please enter caracteristic below",
                        inputType: 'textarea',
                        callback: putTooltip,
                    });
                    function putTooltip(result) {
                        layer.bindTooltip(result, { 'permanent': false, 'interactive': true });
                    }

                    feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {}; // Intialize layer.feature

                    feature.type = feature.type || "Feature"; // Intialize feature.type
                    var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {}; // Intialize feature.properties
                    props.title = "my title";       /// here I would like some prompt
                    props.content = "my content";   /// here too

                    ////// saving into geojson ////

                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
                    var type = e.layerType;
                    var layer = e.layer;
                    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
                    var shape = layer.toGeoJSON()
                    var shape_for_db = JSON.stringify(shape);
                    console.log(shape_for_db);
                    return shape_for_db;
                });
            }); //// end of draw:created
```

I didn't know how to do it, and especially if it is the right way to do it directly into the JavaScript file. I can save my newly created polygon on my computer and open it, and I can add properties directly inside every geometry I create :

```
feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {}; // Intialize layer.feature

                    feature.type = feature.type || "Feature"; // Intialize feature.type
                    var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {}; // Intialize feature.properties
                    props.title = "my title";       /// here I would like some user input text
                    props.content = "my content";   /// here too :)
```

But I would like someone to add a polygon, enter information in it, and save this geoJson file into a SQL database (Ideally). I try to made a file before trying to save it on a SQL database...